L jump at edge in Quoridor?
My friend and I got into this predicament playing quoridor. The red pawn is one space away from winning. The white pawn was backed up and needs to go the length of the board.
Can the red pawn do a legal L jump to win?  My friend says it cannot because it can only L jump if a fence is behind the pawn because that’s what the rules say. The rules don’t state that the boundary is the same as a fence. Anyone ever run into this?


I don't see how this is a duplicate. This scenario was never mentioned in the linked question, nor its answers.
